# When a user-defined type is called, what causes tp_new to reference object_new?

Tags: python, types, cpython, language-implementation

When a user-defined type is called to create a new object, `type_call` is called. Its first parameter is `PyObject *type`. Then, `type->tp_new` is called to create the object.

I'm reading Eli Bendersky's [article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/04/16/python-object-creation-sequence) (And following along [CPyton's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c)) where it is explained that in such case, calling `tp_new` invokes `object_new`. Here's how it works (`Joe` is a user-defined type; Italic is added):

> Since the type parameter passed to `type_call` in our case is `Joe`,
>   and `Joe` does not define a custom `__new__` method, *then
>   `type->tp_new` defers to the `tp_new` slot of the base type*.
>
> The base type of `Joe` [...] is `object`. The `object.tp_new` slot is
>   implemented in CPython by the `object_new` function in
>   `Objects/typeobject.c`.

So, if I understand this correctly, it follows that if `type->tp_new` references `object_new`, then the runtime type of `type` must be `PyBaseObject_Type*` (Because only `PyBaseObject_Type.tp_new` references `object_new`).

My question: What are the steps - preceding the invocation of `type_call` - that makes `type` point to a `PyBaseObject_Type` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've misunderstood how things work. During setup of a user-defined class, if the class doesn't define its own `__new__`, its `tp_new` is copied from the "dominant base". You can see the code for this in [`inherit_special`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Objects/typeobject.c#L4687):

```
    if (base != &PyBaseObject_Type ||
        (type->tp_flags & Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE)) {
        if (type->tp_new == NULL)
            type->tp_new = base->tp_new;
    }
```

There is no need for the class itself to be `PyBaseObject_Type`, or "a `PyBaseObject_Type` variable".

Comment: Thanks. Regardless, if you think my question is worth a downvote, I'd be glad to hear why and improve.